# How to plot Multiline Graphs Via Seaborn library in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have written a code that looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
T = np.array([10.03,100.348,1023.385])
power1 = np.array([100000,86000,73000])
power2 = np.array([1008000,95000,1009000])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Size': T, 'Encrypt_Time': power1, 'Decrypt_Time': power2})
exp1= sns.lineplot(data=df1)
plt.savefig('exp1.png')
exp1_smooth= sns.lmplot(x='Size', y='Time', data=df, ci=None, order=4, truncate=False)
plt.savefig('exp1_smooth.png')
```

That gives me Graph_1:
[image]

The `Size` = x- axis is a constant line but as you can see in my code it varies from (10,100,1000).

How does this produces a constant line? I want to produce a multiline graph with x-axis = Size(T),y- axis= Encrypt_Time and Decrypt_Time (power1 & power2).

Also I wanted to plot a smooth graph of the same graph I am getting right now but it gives me error. What needs to be done to achieve a smooth multi-line graph with x-axis = Size(T),y- axis= Encrypt_Time and Decrypt_Time (power1 & power2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it not the issue, the line represents for `size` looks like constant but it NOT.

Can see that values of size in range `10-1000` while the minimum division of y-axis is 20,000 (20 times bigger), make it look like a horizontal line on your graph.
You can try with a bigger values to see the slope clearly.

If you want 'size` as x-axis, you can try below example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
T = np.array([10.03,100.348,1023.385])
power1 = np.array([100000,86000,73000])
power2 = np.array([1008000,95000,1009000])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Size': T, 'Encrypt_Time': power1, 'Decrypt_Time': power2})
fig = plt.figure()
fig = sns.lineplot(data=df1, x='Size',y='Encrypt_Time' )
fig = sns.lineplot(data=df1, x='Size',y='Decrypt_Time' )
```

Comment: I wanted to take size on x-axis and plot y ( Encrypt_Time And Decrypt_Time) for it. Something like, line1: (x1=10.03,y1=100000) ,(x2=100.348, y2=86000),(x3=1023.385,y3=73000) 
line 2 (X1=10.03, Y1=1008000) ,(X2=100.348, Y2=95000),(X3=1023.385,Y3=109000)

Comment: @rishabhgoyal Hi, you can try my edited answer.